# Paho MQTT on uvicorn server

Tags: python, mqtt, paho, uvicorn

I have a very simple `FastAPI` python server:

```
import io
import os
import sys
import json
import time
from PIL import Image
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, HTTPException, UploadFile, Form

# Initialize FastAPI
app = FastAPI()

# Initialize ENV variables
args = {
    'broker'    : os.environ.get('BROKER', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port'      : int(os.environ.get('PORT', '1883')),
    'topic'     : os.environ.get('TOPIC', 'topic')
}
    
# Initialize MQTT
print('Connecting to MQTT broker {}:{}.'.format(args['broker'], args['port']), flush=True)
mqtt_client = mqtt.Client(args['model'])
mqtt_client.connect(args['broker'], args['port'])

@app.get("/")
async def info():
    return "Send a POST request to / with an image\nWill publish results to topic {}".format(args['topic'])
    
@app.post("/")
async def run(image: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        start = time.time()
        
        # Read request data
        contents = await image.read()
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(contents))

        # Do something with the image
        results = ["todo"]
        print('Process took {} seconds'.format(time.time() - start), flush=True)
        
        # Publish to MQTT topic
        print('Publish to MQTT {}'.format(args['topic']), flush=True)
        (rc, mid) = mqtt_client.publish(args['topic'], json.dumps(results), qos=2)
        print("Code {} while sending message {}: {}".format(rc, mid, mqtt.error_string(rc)))
        #if not rc == mqtt.MQTT_ERR_SUCCESS: print("Code {} while sending message {}: {}".format(rc, mid, mqtt.error_string(rc)))

        # Format response
        data = {}
        data['res'] = results
        data['count'] = len(results)
        data['success'] = True
        return data
    except:
        e = sys.exc_info()[1]
        print('Python error with no Exception handler:')
        print('Traceback error: {}'.format(e))
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))
```

My aim is to publish the results both on HTTP response and on MQTT topic.
The MQTT connection seems to be working.

When I send a request to the web server, the following logs appear:

```
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/app']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:80 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using statreload    
Connecting to MQTT broker 192.168.1.201:1883.
INFO:     Started server process [7]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.

Process took 0.025616168975830078 seconds
Publish to MQTT topic/mytopic
Code 0 while sending message 1: No error.
INFO:     10.42.6.1:39480 - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Running TensorFlow interpreter on image
Process took 0.023961544036865234 seconds
Publish to MQTT topic/mytopic
Code 0 while sending message 2: No error.
INFO:     10.42.6.1:39480 - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Running TensorFlow interpreter on image
Process took 0.031525611877441406 seconds
Publish to MQTT topic/mytopic
Code 0 while sending message 3: No error.
INFO:     10.42.6.1:39480 - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

The publish seems to go fine but I can't receive any message (whereas it works directly from command line).

The server is started using command:

```
uvicorn server:app --reload --port 80 --host 0.0.0.0
```

How to run `publish` from another thread ?

Comment: did you start MQTT client before you publish messages? If you start client after publishing messages then it may not get it. It may need special option to keep it for clients which connect after sending message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't started the MQTT client [network loop](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#network-loop).

You should probably add `mqtt_client.loop_start()` after the call to `mqtt_client.connect()`